# Error while custom periods based resampling using resample('W'),sum() in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the data frame ( frame_combined_DF) which looks like this. I need to do custom resampling based on Time_W weeks provided for each SKU.

```
frame_combined_DF

            SKU     Qty     Time        Time_W
WY          
2011-10-17  ABC     12.0    11.0        2
2012-01-16  ABC     20.0    11.0        2
2013-04-08  ABC     6.0     11.0        2
2013-12-02  ABC     2.0     11.0        2
2014-10-27  XYZ     1.0     21.0        3
```

Below is my code

```
for i in ids:
   subset = frame_combined_DF.loc[frame_combined_DF.SKU==i]
   subset.index=subset.WY
   subset.sort_index(inplace=True)
   period=subset.Time_W.unique().astype('int64')[0]
   per=str(period)+'W'
   df = subset.Qty.resample(per).sum()
   new_df = {'WY':df.index, 'Qty':df.values,'SKU':i} 
   newdf = pd.DataFrame(new_df) 
   new_series=new_series.append(newdf)
```

I am getting following error while running this code

```
 ValueError: Offset <0 * Weeks: weekday=6> did not increment date
```

Expected output is as under. Below example is only for 1 SKU. This SKU needs to be re sampled at frequency of 2 weeks, where as SKU XYZ to be resampled for for every three weeks

```
  WY             Qty    SKU
  2011-10-17    12.0    ABC
  2011-10-31    0.0     ABC
  2011-11-14    0.0     ABC
  2011-11-28    0.0     ABC
  2011-12-12    0.0     ABC
  .........................
  .........................
  2012-01-09    20.0    ABC
  2012-01-23    0.0     ABC
  ..........................
```

Comment: Can you share the expected output ?

Comment: updated the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample data I see that *WY* is the index column.

But check whether this column is of *datetime* type (not *string*).
If it is not, run `frame_combined_DF.index = pd.to_datetime(frame_combined_DF.index)`.

Another point to note is that *newdf* is a **DataFrame**, not a *Series*,
so you should append it to a *DataFrame*.

The third remark is that *subset.index = subset.WY* is not needed, because
*WY* is already the index.

And the last thing: Your sample did not define *new_series* (in my solution
I changed it to *result*).

So change your code to:

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for i in frame_combined_DF.SKU.unique():
    subset = frame_combined_DF.loc[frame_combined_DF.SKU==i]
    subset.sort_index(inplace=True)
    period = subset.Time_W.unique().astype('int64')[0]
    per = str(period) + 'W'
    df = subset.Qty.resample(per).sum()
    new_df = {'WY': df.index, 'Qty': df.values, 'SKU': i}
    newdf = pd.DataFrame(new_df)
    result = result.append(newdf, ignore_index=True)
```

and it should run, at least on my computer it gives no error.